# SQL: Update column value conditioned on same column value

Tags: sql, sqlite

On a SQLite database something I thought was very simple doesn't work at least under my conditions.

I have one column with names and some name contains apostrophe (`'`), which I want to remove. I know all names which contains an apostrophe, so I am not trying to query for apostrophes. I am doing something much simpler:

```
UPDATE table SET column_name="name surname1 surname2" WHERE column_name="name surname1'surname2";
```

which doesn't return what I expect. It doesn't produce an error but it doesn't modify any record.

SQL doesn't like reflexivity?

Comment: It's very common and SQLite likes it fine. If there's no error, it worked. If no records were updated, no records match `column_name="name surname1'surname2"`, which is of course possible.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issue with querying the current value of a column to update the same column. Try escaping the single-quote by doubling it e.g. `''`.

See: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html which reads:

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). **A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two
>   single quotes in a row** - as in Pascal.

Therefore, your update should be:

```
UPDATE table SET column_name='name surname1 surname2' WHERE column_name='name surname1''surname2'
```

Update: Added explanation of escape mechanism.

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly explain that the *escaping* is done by doubling the single quote.